# How to suppress warning "It will be removed in version 9.0 of the Android Gradle" for feature pluginandroid.defaults.buildfeatures.aidl

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

According to Android document, the default value of `android.defaults.buildfeatures.aidl` is set to false.

But my project need it. So I update the project's gradle properties file:

```
android.defaults.buildfeatures.aidl=true
```

but AGP gives me warning:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"The option setting 'android.defaults.buildfeatures.aidl=true' is deprecated.\nThe current default is 'false'.\nIt will be removed in version 9.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.","sources":[{}]}
```

How to suppress it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried with this by adding below code in app level `build.gradle` file?

```
android {
   buildFeatures {
        aidl true
    }
}
```

Comment: good gravy, why is this not on the AIDL docs page? Took me an hour to figure out how to *just* generate AIDL without building the rest of the module since of course the rest of the module can't build without the AIDL generated code!